# How to update a function's input by its own output

Tags: python, recursion

I am scraping a web page with a table that has multiple pages. I have a function that finds the next page button and hits it. The function needs to return to the main table page to do that. I have the link to that main table page hardcoded in a variable.

Once I moved to e.g page number 2, how do I update that table page link to the new page link? so that once it's done going inside elements of the table, it'll go back to the 2nd-page link and move on from there, not the first page.

```
def nextPage(driver, desiredPage):
driver.get(desiredPage)
time.sleep(55)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath(XPATH WRITTEN HERE)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
time.sleep(45)
next_page = driver.current_url

return next_page
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a while loop, to call the method again and again. You may choose a condition on `page_nb` or another variable to count, to avoid infinite code to run

```
page_nb = 1
while page_nb != 99:
    page_nb = nextPage(driver, page_nb)
```